# How to apply llvm passes using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm

We have implemented a LLVM pass and compiled it to a library (called `libMyPass.so`).

We want to apply this pass to a project (all its source code files) which uses `cmake` to build it. Is there a way to do so in cmake?

Generally, we used `clang` to emit llvm bit code from a source file, `opt` to apply this pass to the bit code, `llc` to translate the new bit code to assembly language and `clang` again to compile assembly language to executable. Can I encapsulate this process using `cmake`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look or even use [this](https://github.com/compor/llvm-ir-cmake-utils) repo that implements the various steps as `cmake` commands.

The gist of it is that creates various commands (using the `cmake`'s `add_custom_command`) basically do exactly what you're looking for using the various LLVM subtools in conjunction with the various `cmake` target properties, in order to create the IR generation commands from source and to native binary code (i.e. `.o`).

For example, using `llvmir_attach_bc_target()` attaches to a top-level `cmake` target and creates a (unoptimized) `.bc` file for each source file in the [SOURCES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SOURCES.html) property of it.

It contains various examples in the same repo that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. You should copy a little more info from your site.